# how to integrate auto-scheduled email service with user interface asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have created a web services that do auto emailing from Global.cs. I used the reference [Code Project Ref for Simulate WS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

for auto scheduled email services, and it is sending email every 2 minutes from my gmail account to another gmail account. Now, I want to go further based on this success. I want to have UI interface where user can choose whom to send, start date and end date in web form and make them work.

User can make selectoin on whom to send from ListBox and start/end date from here. Then, user can set as daily sending email. I have created a table for User Name, User Email, Start Date and End Date. I do not know how to link input from this GUI to Global.cs. Any idea, please. I also want to make sure that the service should stop running at End Date. Please adivse. 
This is my code for auto email services.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{   //private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Data Source=(local);InitialCatalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
// private const string LOG_FILE = @"c:\temp\Cachecallback.txt";
// private const string MSMQ_NAME = ".\\private$\\ASPNETService";

private const string DummyCacheItemKey = "abcdefgh";
public static ArrayList _JobQueue = new ArrayList();


public Global()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterCacheEntry();
}

private void RegisterCacheEntry()
{
    // Prevent duplicate key addition
    if (null != HttpContext.Current.Cache[DummyCacheItemKey]) return;

    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(DummyCacheItemKey, "Test", null, DateTime.MaxValue,
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
        new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemovedCallback));
}

/// <summary>
/// Callback method which gets invoked whenever the cache entry expires.
/// We can do our "service" works here.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key"></param>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <param name="reason"></param>
public void CacheItemRemovedCallback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Cache item callback: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

    // Do the service works
    DoWork();

    // We need to register another cache item which will expire again in one
    // minute. However, as this callback occurs without any HttpContext, we do not
    // have access to HttpContext and thus cannot access the Cache object. The
    // only way we can access HttpContext is when a request is being processed which
    // means a webpage is hit. So, we need to simulate a web page hit and then 
    // add the cache item.
    HitPage();
}

/// <summary>
/// Hits a local webpage in order to add another expiring item in cache
/// </summary>
private void HitPage()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadData(DummyPageUrl);
}

/// <summary>
/// Asynchronously do the 'service' works
/// </summary>
private void DoWork()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Begin DoWork...");
    Debug.WriteLine("Running as: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

 DoSomeEmailSendStuff();

    Debug.WriteLine("End DoWork...");
}


/// <summary>
/// Test email send
/// </summary>
private void DoSomeEmailSendStuff()
{
    try
    {
        string mailbody;

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.To.Add("def@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com", "Joe Testing");


        mailMessage.Subject = "Test from ASP .NET";
        mailbody = "This is test only from ASP .NET for auto email scheduling";
        mailMessage.Body = "<html><body>" + mailbody.Replace("\n", "<br/>") + "</body></html>";
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        // Create the credentials to login to the gmail account associated with my custom domain
        string sendEmailsFrom = "abc@gmail.com";
        string sendEmailsFromPassword = "xxxxxxxxxx";

        NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(sendEmailsFrom, sendEmailsFromPassword);


        SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
        mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        //mailClient.Timeout = 20000;
        mailClient.Credentials = cred;
        //mailClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        mailClient.Send(mailMessage);


    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(x);
    }
}


protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // If the dummy page is hit, then it means we want to add another item in cache
  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() == DummyPageUrl)
    {
    // Add the item in cache and when succesful, do the work.
    RegisterCacheEntry();
    }
}
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

#region Web Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
        {
             this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        }
#endregion
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For that the first thing to do would be to add some more fields in your Global.cs class file. Which would handle the values that the user would use.

```
private string Recipient;
private DateTime StartTime;
private DateTime EndTime;
```

... you can add more fields if you want to add more fields and so on and so forth.

Then you can use the Form to populate these fields on the POST request like this

```
if(IsPost) {
   // get the form items and add details to the Global.cs
}
```

Once you're done adding the details, execute the function that you already have and add the details from Global.cs.

Comment: Thank for your advice. Can you tell me in more details for //get the form items and add detailed to the Global.cs? In the form, I add data of Recipient, Start Time and Date Time, and save in db of ms SQL. then, fetch those data to Global.cs . Is it correct way to do that? If you have any sample, please share with me. Appreciate for your help.